# rviz: symbol lookup error

Tags: ros, rviz, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Fresh Ros Kinetic install on Ubuntu 16.04 (installed today). Try to launch RVIZ and get this error:

```
rviz: symbol lookup error: /opt/ros/kinetic/lib/librviz.so: undefined symbol:
_ZNK9QTreeView16viewportSizeHintEv
```

Things i've tried (that have not worked):

- Rebooting
- sudo apt dist-upgrade
- googling this problem
- Deleting, and remaking my catkin workspace.

Possibly relevant info:

This is a pretty standard installation of Ubuntu + ROS and the system install is pretty fresh as well. Only non-standard stuff I've done so far is I've installed nVidia video drivers to make a 1080 TI video card work and I've updated the kernel to version 4.15.2 to resolve a system clock drift issue with i9 processors.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/282495/rviz:-symbol-lookup-error/) by [rb](https://answers.ros.org/users/13396/rb/) on ROS Answers with karma: 130 on 2018-02-12

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2018-02-12**:
It's missing a Qt symbol, is Qt installed and if so, what version?

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2018-02-12**:
Also, did you install rviz from apt or did you build it from source? If not from source, what's in your catkin workspace that might affect rviz? Are you using any custom rviz plugins? Can you start rviz if you use the default configuration?

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2018-02-12**:
I just tried it on my 16.04 machine (`sudo apt update; sudo apt dist-upgrade`) and rviz runs fine. You can run the default configuration with `rviz -d /opt/ros/kinetic/share/rviz/default.rviz` (assuming you installed from debs).

**Comment by [rb](https://answers.ros.org/users/13396/rb/) on 2018-02-13**:
QT 4.8.7 and qt 5.5.1 are installed. Running with default configuration makes no difference, identical error (Since this is first time opening RViz it should be default config anyway)

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2018-02-13**:
Perhaps it is picking up Qt4 instead of Qt5? I'm not sure why/how that would happen, but it could cause the symbol issues you're seeing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Problem solved. Turned out that rviz was grabbing the wrong QT dependencies from an unrelated program installed on the computer. Thanks William for tips of looking into QT.

Before:

```
$ ldd /opt/ros/kinetic/lib/librviz.so | grep Qt
    libQt5Widgets.so.5 => /opt/EVT/eCapture/QT/lib/libQt5Widgets.so.5 (0x00007fd0ad22c000)
    libQt5Gui.so.5 => /opt/EVT/eCapture/QT/lib/libQt5Gui.so.5 (0x00007fd0ab053000)
    libQt5Core.so.5 => /opt/EVT/eCapture/QT/lib/libQt5Core.so.5 (0x00007fd0aa9c9000)
```

Fix:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

After:

```
$ ldd /opt/ros/kinetic/lib/librviz.so | grep Qt
libQt5Widgets.so.5 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Widgets.so.5 (0x00007ff360453000)
libQt5Gui.so.5 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Gui.so.5 (0x00007ff35e38a000)
libQt5Core.so.5 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5 (0x00007ff35deb4000)
```

---

Originally posted by [rb](https://answers.ros.org/users/13396/rb/) with karma: 130 on 2018-02-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [utk50](https://answers.ros.org/users/58055/utk50/) on 2020-08-18**:
Hi, I have ubuntu 18.04 and ros melodic running and I am facing the same issue.

When I execute:

```
ldd /opt/ros/melodic/lib/librviz.so | grep Qt
```

I am already getting

```
libQt5Widgets.so.5 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Widgets.so.5 (0x00007f997c7a3000)
libQt5Gui.so.5 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Gui.so.5 (0x00007f997a45a000) 
libQt5Core.so.5 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5 (0x00007f9979d0f000)
```

But I am still getting the symbol lookup error. Any suggestions?

**Comment by [ranjeet](https://answers.ros.org/users/39282/ranjeet/) on 2021-01-31**:
Did you find any solution yet?